# Why does git submodule build depend on node modules of parent project?

Tags: node.js, git, build, git-submodules

https://github.com/hyperbotauthor/chessopsnpmts

This project has a git submodule, which in separation builds according to its own `package.json`'s build script.

```
[submodule "chessground"]
    path = chessground
    url = https://github.com/ornicar/chessground
```

However if I run the same build script when I import it in my project as a git submodule, then the build fails with cryptic error messages about missing modules which are actually not missing.

I suspected that this has to do something with the parent project's node modules, so I renamed the node modules folder of the parent project for the time of the build, and it succeeded. So now I have a build script that renames, builds, then restores original name of the folder of parent node modules.

```json
"buildcg": "mv node_modules node_modules_ignore ; cd chessground && yarn && yarn dist && cd .. ; mkdir vendor ; cp chessground/dist/chessground.js vendor ; printf '\n\n// es export\n\nexport { Chessground }\n' >> vendor/chessground.js ; mv node_modules_ignore node_modules"
```

Is the build standing in a git module's folder dependent of parent project's installed node modules ( every module is installed locally to the parent project )?

Comment: Git has no control over whether someone uses its submodules inappropriately. That appears to be the case here: whoever made this set of node modules made a tangled mess of it, and left that to be a problem for you. But dependencies are hard in general.

Comment: Thanks for these insights. Indeed it is unlikely to be a git submodule problem. Rather a Node.js ( which was also a tag to the question ) problem. In module resolution Node.js may go backward to parent folder and pull in dependencies not wished by the submodule. If I change node modules folder name, then this unwanted module resolution fails. Just guessing.